# How to convert a string to JSON format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I was getting list in array form. So at first place i converted array list to string-

```
 var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(result);
 myJsonString="[{"productId":"PI_NAME",
                      "firstName":null,
                       "lastName":null,
                       "customer":null
                },
                  {"productId":"PI_NAME",
                        "firstName":null,
                         "lastName":null,
                    "customer":null
                }]"
```

But again i need to convert myJsonString to Json format, What i need to do? I mean i need to replace 1st" and last ", I guess

Comment: The data format is called "JSON" (JavaScript Object Notation), not "Jason" (a person's name).

Comment: ohh sorry.. it was a typo.. :)

Comment: Just call JSON.parse(...), the opposite of JSON.stringify. Reading documentation could have helped you.

Comment: look for JSON.parse() method

Comment: The `JSON.stringify()` function converts an object/array into JSON data.  It returns a string.  What is your question here?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you try to explain a bit more what you are trying to do?  It seems you may not understand what JSON is.  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  It's a way of representing data as a string.  The `JSON.stringify()` function gives you a string that is JSON data.  It is in "JSON format".  I'm not sure what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Initially result was a list of array.. So i thought to convert to jason format. So tried using JSON.stringify wrongly.. Thanks for your explanation. got your point. thank you all for your kind answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to call parse now.

```
JSON.parse(myJsonString)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you ever find yourself building a JSON string by concatenating strings, know that this is probably the wrong approach.

I don't really understand how the first line of your code relates to the second, in that you are not doing anything with JSON-encoded string output from `result`, but instead just overwriting this on the following line.

So, I am going to limit my answer to show how you could better form JSON from an object/array definition like you have.  That might look like this:

```
// build data structure first
// in this example we are using javascript array and object literal notation.
var objArray = [
    {
        "productId":"PI_NAME",
        "firstName":null,
        "lastName":null,
        "customer":null
    },{
        "productId":"PI_NAME",
        "firstName":null,
        "lastName":null,
        "customer":null
    }
];
// now that your data structure is built, encoded it to JSON
var JsonString = JSON.stringify(objArray);
```

Now if you want to work with JSON-encoded data, You just do the opposite:

```
var newObjArray = JSON.parse(JsonString);
```

These are really the only two commands you should ever use in javascript when encoding/decoding JSON.  You should not try to manually build or modify JSON strings, unless you have a very specific reason to do so.